# Crystal Reports - Display Array Parameter as String in Report Heading

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports

I have a dynamic parameter that prompts users to select values from a string field to be used in a report. I'd like to then display the values the user selected in the report heading for reference, but am unsure how to print out the array into string. Right now If I drop the parameter field on the report, it will only display the first of X selections. I can't figure out how to get this array of string values to print all values.

User selects -> Field A, Field B, Field C on the parameter page
Need to print out {?Selection}

Answer (score 1):

simple way is to use function Join

```
Join({?Parameter},",")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Local NumberVar Temp := Count({?Parameter});
    Local NumberVar counter := 1;
    Local StringVar List;
    While counter in [1 to Temp] 
    Do
    ( 
    if counter=1 then List := {?Parameter}[counter]
    else List:=List&", "& {?Parameter}[counter];
    counter := counter + 1;
    );
    List`

Comment: create a formula with this as the code and it will print out your {?Parameter} text